# Palette: A Multicoloured Grid Deduction Puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

<sup>*This is an entry for [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #44: Introduce a new grid deduction genre to the community](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7080/28719).*</sup>

I've been dreaming up potential logic puzzles involving colours, and how they mix to form new colours. This logic puzzle uses the three primary colours (in the additive colour space, how light mixes) to form 8 combinations. I think I'll call it a Palette puzzle. (open to suggestions)

The rules are as follows:

- Fill each region with a colour from the list below
- The numbers along the side and top indicate the number of squares in that row or column which include that primary colour (red, green, or blue) in its composition
- No two regions of the same combined colour may share an edge

---

The possible colours are:

- *Black* (none of the primary colours)
- *Red* (only red)
- *Blue* (only blue)
- *Green* (only green)
- *Cyan* (green and blue, no red)
- *Magenta* (red and blue, no green)
- *Yellow* (red and green, no blue)
- *White* (all three primary colours)

[image]

The puzzle has a unique solution, but might require guessing (or looking far ahead)

**Edit**: Apologies, the solution is *not* unique, but you should be able to figure out the intended solution.

Comment: Can you explain the division of the puzzle?

Comment: @PrinceDeepthinker I'm not sure exactly what you mean, the darker lines in the grid divide it up into regions. The regions exactly represent the division of colours in the puzzle's solution

Comment: I like the concept of the puzzle, but the lack of unique solution was a real downer. :-(

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I did intend it to be unique, but I must’ve missed it. As you can tell, I created the puzzle from the solution, and similar to Nonograms it doesn’t always make a unique puzzle. Perhaps I’ll try again with a unique one!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a *little bit of guessing* I finished it, and it's clearly a

> rainbow!!

grid

> [image]

Comment: Very good, but you can keep going! have a look at green column 6

Comment: @MatthewJensen done now :)